# Mean Value related problem.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I'm working on a function $f : \left[a,a+h\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I know that $f$ satisfies the conditions of the Mean Value Theorem thus I have $\theta \in \left(0,1\right)$ such that $f\left(a+h\right)-f\left(a\right)=hf'\left(a+\theta h\right)$.

If $f$ and $a$ are fixed, if we write $\theta\left(h\right)$ for the value of $\theta$ that corresponds to some $h$ and if $f''\left(a\right)$ exists, I'm looking for a proof that the limit as $h$ tends to $0$ of $\theta\left(h\right)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I believe so (I have tried with some particular functions) but I can't complete a proof.

My attempt:

$f''\left(a\right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(f'\left(a+h\right)-f'\left(a\right)\right)}{h}$ 
I can transform this to have $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\left(f'\left(a+\theta h\right)-f'\left(a\right)\right)}{\theta h}$ and then replace $f'\left(a+\theta h\right)$ byt its value above. I've thought about using L'Hospital's Rule but I think it is dodgy and does not seem useful. I have also seen that $\frac{f\left(a+h\right)-f\left(a\right)}{h}$ looks like $f'\left(a\right)$ but can't use it.

That's pretty much all I have, can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(a+h)-f(a)=f'(a)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)h^2+o(h^2)
$$
and
$$
f'(a+h\theta) = f'(a)+f''(a)h\theta + o(h\theta).
$$
In the last equation I just used the definition of $f''(a)$.
Hence
$$
f'(a)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)h^2 + o(h^2)=f'(a)h+f''(a)\theta h^2 + o(h^2\theta).
$$
Dividing by $h^2$ we deduce
$$
\frac{1}{2}f''(a) = f''(a) \theta +o(1).
$$
If $f''(a) \neq 0$, then $\theta \to 1/2$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation o(h²), can you clarify? And do you really mean the first = in the first line or is it a -?

Comment: $o(h^2)$ is any function such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{o(h^2)}{h^2}=0$.

Comment: Yes, I've added a remark at the beginning. I don't know if it works under the minimal assumption that $f''(a)$ exists.

Comment: It is indeed not given that f''(a) is continuous (neither that the second derivative exists at any other point than a) :/ Isn't there a more direct proof that wouldn't use these facts?

Comment: It seems to me that my approach (I had a few misprints) works under your minimal assumptions.

Comment: I'll have a closer look at it, thank you!

Comment: I don't actually think that I fully understand your reasoning since I'm not used to these notations :/